# Get total of referenced tables' column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum

Consider a database of accounts and deposits:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
    id int not null primary key,
    name varchar(63)
);

CREATE TABLE deposits (
    id int not null primary key,
    account int references accounts(id),
    dollars decimal(15, 2),
    status enum('pending','complete') 
);


insert into accounts values
(0, 'us'),
(1, 'europe'),
(2, 'asia');

insert into deposits values
(0, 0, 10, 'pending'),
(1, 0, 20, 'complete'),
(2, 1, 100, 'complete'),
(3, 1, 200, 'pending'),
(4, 1, 300, 'complete'),
(5, 2, 1000, 'pending');
```

I would like to get a total of all the `complete` deposits per bank, this is the expected result:

```
+--------+-----+
| us     | 20  |
| europe | 400 |
| asia   | 0   |
+--------+-----+
```

This is the SQL that I tried, but it does not work as expected:

```
SELECT
    a.name, SUM(d.dollars)
FROM
    accounts a
  INNER JOIN
    deposits d ON (a.id = d.account AND d.status='complete');
```

This is the result that it gave:

```
+--------+-----+
| us     | 420 |
+--------+-----+
```

[Here is an SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce81f/5/0) of the current code.

What have I done wrong, and how can I get the expected sum?

Comment: you forgot group by bank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 SELECT
a.name, coalesce(SUM(d.dollars),0) as sums
FROM
accounts a
left JOIN
deposits d ON (a.id = d.account AND d.status='complete')
group by  a.name
order by sums desc
```

you should use LEFT JOIN , and you should use GROUP BY also.

[**LOOK DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91103/6)

Answer (score 1):

You should use grouping by `a.name` (or maybe even `a.id`) and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (if you want to get non-present values).

EDIT:

```
SELECT
    a.name, SUM(d.dollars)
FROM
    accounts a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    deposits d ON (a.id = d.account AND d.status='complete')
GROUP BY a.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
a.name, IF(SUM(d.dollars) IS NULL, 0, SUM(d.dollars) )
FROM
    accounts a
  LEFT JOIN
    deposits d ON (a.id = d.account AND d.status='complete')
GROUP BY a.name ORDER BY a.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

By joining accounts with deposits you only make sure that you sum dollars for deposits that are linked to an account. If you would also Group by the account name, or even account Id then you will get a Sum/bank.